# how to completely remove cairo dock and reinstall it

Tags: 13.04, cairo-dock

I installed gnome shell and when i did the cairo dock is not opening at all it opens the maintenance mode and i can not edit the preferences i want to uninstall it and reinstall maybe it'll help ti fix it or if anyone have any idea that would help
I installed it from sofware center and i tried `purge` and it wasn't worked

I tried cairo-dock -ol debug and that was the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5648625/)

Comment: How was it installed?

Comment: from the software center

Comment: did you try Google?  See [the first hit for "cairo dock maintenance mode"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=888958)

Answer (score 2):

I installed it, on my system just to see how it works, and I removed it.  This how I did it:

To completely remove Cairo dock, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

Also if you have Synaptic Package Manager installed, you can search for cairo-dock, and unckeck cairo-dock and cairo-dock-plug-ins.

You can go back to the USC, and remove Cairo Dock.

I just tried it on another machine, and tried the first command, install it form the USC it, and it was removed.

If it starts in maintenance mode, then do this:

Quit Cairo-Dock 
Remove this:

```
~/.config/cairo-dock/
```

Launch Cairo-Dock in a terminal with :

```
cairo-dock -o
```

If you have the maintenance mode again, can you launch Cairo-Dock with

```
cairo-dock -ol debug
```

and post the output

One last thing.  Install synaptic package manager if you don't have it installed.  You can install it by just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed launch it from dash, and when it opens search for Cairo

[image]

Highlight all Cairo entries

[image]

Right click, and choose Mark for Complete Removal

[image]

Comment: it did not worked, the command `purge` uninstalled it but when i reinstalled it it gave me the maintenance mode

Comment: I just added the info if it starts in maintenance mode.

Comment: i tried to delete that folder and it didn't worked so i just added the output, and it was too long so i cut some of it in the beginning so i can post it

Comment: I fixed the post for you, and I have added more info in the answer.  Take a look at it.